# How xterm.js apply fullscreen addon?

Tags: xtermjs

I used xterm.js in a html file, Import the xterm.js via src:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/plugins/xterm/dist/xterm.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/plugins/xterm/dist/addons/fullscreen/fullscreen.css" />
  <script src="/static/plugins/xterm/dist/xterm.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/plugins/xterm/dist/addons/fullscreen/fullscreen.js"></script>
</head>

  <script>
     var term = new Terminal();
     term.open(element);
  </script>
```

How to apply Fullscreen addon? I have referenced official link:
https://xtermjs.org/docs/api/addons/fullscreen/
but not work for me!

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `Terminal.applyAddon(fullscreen);` in front of the `var term = new Terminal();`.